# How to extend prolog driver and determine number of columns and rows by reading an eps file

Tags: prolog

Good day! I would like to ask for help in understanding Prolog code as well as learning how to extend its functionality. Based on my limited yet newbie knowledge of programming, the function of the first given code (is quite like a main file), everything originates from it and thus it is the first file that is run before calling any other function.

```
main.pl

printSequences([]).
printSequences([Sequence|Sequences]):-
    writeln(Sequence),
    printSequences(Sequences).

loadHelpers:-
    ['helpers'],
    ['part01'],
    ['part02'],
    ['part03'],
    ['part04'].

part01:-
    readExtremePegSolitaireFile('test04.eps',_,Game),
    printGame(Game),
    columnsAndRows(Game).

part02:-
    readExtremePegSolitaireFile('part01test01.eps',_,Game),
    printGame(Game),
    openSpaces(Game).

part03:-
    readExtremePegSolitaireFile('test04.single.eps',_,Game),
    printGame(Game),
    setof(Moves,fewestMoves(Game,Moves),AllMoves),
    writeln(moves),
    printSequences(AllMoves).

part04:-
    readExtremePegSolitaireFile('test04.eps',_,Game),
    printGame(Game),
    noIslands(Game).
```

I don't think I have any problems understanding the first given code above, but my problem is mostly with this second given code and how to go about manipulating other files. I can't seem to understand the prefix part (is this the definition of a list of lists?) Also am I correct that most of the other functions are declared in this helper file to make the code more organized?

```
helpers.pl

:- module( helpers,
     [ readExtremePegSolitaireFile/3
     , printGame/1
     ]
    ).

prefix([H],[]).
prefix([H|T],[H|PreT]):-
    prefix(T,PreT).

readExtremePegSolitaireFile(File,Moves,Game):-
    open(File,read,Input),
    read(Input,Moves),
    readGame(Input,Temp),
    prefix(Temp,Game),
    close(Input).

readGame(Input,[]):-
    at_end_of_stream(Input),
    !.
readGame(Input,[Row|Rows]):-
    \+ at_end_of_stream(Input),
    read(Input,Row),
    readGame(Input,Rows).

printGame(Game):-
    writeln(game),
    printRows(Game).

printRows([]).
printRows([Row|Rows]):-
    writeln(Row),
    printRows(Rows).
```

Last is a peg solitaire board that is given with the first line being the list of moves performed and the following lines are the board declarations (1,2,3,4 - players, x - peg, and '-' as empty spaces)

```
test04.eps

[r,d,u,r,l,l,l,d,l,u,r,r].
[2,-,x,x,x,x,x].
[x,x,-,x,-,x,x].
[x,3,x,-,x,-,x].
[x,-,4,x,x,x,x].
[x,x,-,x,x,-,x].
[x,x,x,1,-,x,x].
[x,x,x,x,x,x,x].
```

I would like to know how one would be able to calculate the number of columns and rows via a query columnsAndRows(Game). My first plan of action was to use something like this: (Which would be able to calculate the length of the rows by counting each element in the list however, it seems to have calculated all the elements in the list. 2 things that I noticed was:

1. It didn't stop at the end of the row
2. Apparently it didn't print the entire board, it was missing the last line of the board!

```
columnsAndRows(Game) :- 
    flatten(Game, FlatList),
    length(FlatList,FlatListSize),
    writeln(FlatListSize).

?- [a04tests].
?- loadHelpers.
?- part01.
game
[2,-,x,x,x,x,x]
[x,x,-,x,-,x,x]
[x,3,x,-,x,-,x]
[x,-,4,x,x,x,x]
[x,x,-,x,x,-,x]
[x,x,x,1,-,x,x]
42
true
```

I'm honestly really lost and I'd appreciate any guidance as to where to begin, or even a process flow for this program. Many thanks!

Comment: It doesn't print the entire board because you throw away the last row. You read all of it in `readGame/2`, but then you call `prefix/2` on the temporary board that you have read.

Comment: Ohh I see, ty very much!